# pip3 setup.py install_requires PEP 508 git URL for private repo

Tags: python, git, pip, setup.py

I am trying to run:

`pip3 install -e .`

in my Python project where I have the following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    install_requires=[
        "anotherpackage@git+git@bitbucket.org:myorg/anotherpackage.git"
    ]
)
```

but it fails with:

```
error in mypackage setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid URL given
```

I guess it is correct about the format of my URL as [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#id26) doesn't allow specifying git user name for ssh clone URLs.

What is the correct syntax for PEP 508 URLs with git+ssh protocol for `install_requires` dependency for private git repositories (in this case hosted on BitBucket)? What is the syntax for specifying a specific branch, tag or sha?

### More context to avoid XY problem

I have an internal Python project that depends on multiple internally developed Python packages. I would like to avoid the necessity for hosting my own PIP repository in the organisation and thus I am trying to use git URLs directly. I need to use ssh protocol for git URLs as all the users have their ssh keys configured and it would be cumbersome to ask all the users to configure their app passwords in BitBuckets (I have 2FA required and the regular user password doesn't work).

I have already tried to use:

#### `dependency_links`

```
setup(
    name='mypackage',
    install_requires=[
        "anotherpackage==0.0.1"
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        "git+git@bitbucket.org:myorg/anotherpackage.git@0.0.1#egg=anotherpackage-0.0.1"
    ]
)
```

But they are deprecated and they are ignored by `pip3 install -e .`. According to documentation I've found, PEP 508 URLs should be used instead.

#### `requirements.txt` file with entries duplicated from `install_requires` entries

I have a `requirements.txt` file with:

```
-e git+git@bitbucket.org:myorg/anotherpackage.git@0.0.1#egg=anotherpackage
```

and I use `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` instead of `pip3 install -e .`. It works but is suboptimal as I have to keep both `setyp.py` and `requirements.txt` in sync.

If there is any other recommended solution for my problem I would like to learn about it :)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Python packaging, but I'm pretty familiar with Git. Are you entirely sure about the `git+git@bitbucket.org` part of your URL? I'd expect that `@` to be `://`, expressing a protocol: `git+git://bitbucket.org/...` (I'm also confused by the `anotherpackage@` prefix, but for now I'm assuming that comes from PEP 508, even though I can't find a clear explanation in the PEP itself with a quick glance.)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know it should be `://` according to PEP508 and I tried that but it was also failing. Anyway, I delved into pip source code and figured it out. Let me add an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After checking `pip` source code I found the correct syntax for private BitBucket repositories.

The general form for the packages with URLs is `<package name>@<URI>` and the URI must start with a `<scheme>://`.

So I fixed it to:

`anotherpackage@git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:myorg/anotherpackage.git`

and then I was getting a different error - this time `git` command (invoked by `pip`) was complaining about repository URL `ssh://git@bitbucket.org:myorg/anotherpackage.git`.

I checked the git documentation for the `ssh://` URLs format and found out that hostname and organisation parts must be separated with `/` instead of `:`:

`ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myorg/anotherpackage.git`

This URL works fine. I also learned from the `pip` source code that the actual revision/branch/tag can be specified by appending `@<rev-spec>` so I can specify for example the tag `0.0.1` with the following in `install_requires`:

`anotherpackage@git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:myorg/anotherpackage.git@0.0.1`

The only issue that I still have is that when I change the revision and run `pip3 install -e .` again it doesn't detect the change (even when run with `--upgrade`). I have to manually uninstall the package (`pip3 uninstall anotherpackage`) and run `pip3 install -e .` again.

Comment: Great, the only question/answer I've found for this. I think it makes sense that it won't update the dependencies even with the `--upgrade` flag, as this is the general behavior with other packages. You can always just upgrade the dependency itself if its the only thing that's changed.

Comment: @piotrek-bzdyl, thanks for this. I thought this worked, but this ended up getting the package from pypi or cache, not fetching it from github:

    `Collecting mkdocs-git-committers-plugin@ git+ssh://git@github.com:ojacques/mkdocs-git-committers-plugin.git (from mkdocs-dxc==0.2.0)`
      `Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/59/28729f789f2e74666277e40f953e22294bc3076ebf53137b93af65592874/mkdocs-git-committers-plugin-0.1.8.tar.gz`

Do you experience the same?

Comment: I have the same problem,  I can't install anything from a repo. Pip is always fetching from PyPi

Comment: @ojacques I was using these git  URLs only for my own private packages, I am not sure you can override the public ones published in pip repository.

Comment: can I use file://./mypackage ?

Comment: Thanks for this answer @PiotrekBzdyl! The tip with the separator was what made it finally work. Perhaps you can highlight the correct URL version in your answer. I was a bit confused at the beginning because three out of four URLs in this post use the wrong format.

Comment: What are valid schemes for `<scheme>://`? As @kerolos asked, I also need to install from a local package directory and can't figure out the correct scheme. Perhaps link to pip source you're referencing in your answer?

Comment: Never mind, I came up with a solution to local package dependencies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75630599/9403538).