# How to use local dependency in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

How to specify a local path for a dependency package in setup.py the install_requires key

```
my_workspace
| - my_new_package_root
|   | - setup.py **** my target setup.py
|   | - my_new_package
| - my_packag_root
|   | - setup.py
|   | - my_package
```

This is usually achieved using `pip install -e my_package_root`
but I want to use the setup.py for that.

```
setup(
    ...,

    install_requires=['my_package'],
    ...
)
```

I found this, but it does not tell how to refer to local filesystem

[pip3 setup.py install_requires PEP 508 git URL for private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385900/pip3-setup-py-install-requires-pep-508-git-url-for-private-repo)

Answer (score 0):

Use the file URL, eg:

```py
install_requires=['my_package @ file:///absolute/path/my_package']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to uses this syntax :

```
install_requires=['package @ file:///path/to/my/package']
```

Notes that you have to specify the absolute path for your package.