# How to specify a gitlab repo for `install_requires` in `setup.py`?

Tags: python, git, installation, gitlab

I have a repository `A` which required another repo `B` (`testrepo`). I have therefore added the following content to the file `setup.py` for repo `A`:

```
install_requires=[
    'click>=7.0',
    'GitPython',
    'testrepo @ git+https://mygitlab.ch/somegroup/testrepo.git'
],
```

The testrepo `B` contains a `setup.py` file on itself to install a package names `repo_data`.

When I try to install repo `A` no package `repo_data` is been installed. The `lib/python3.8/site-package` path does not contain a folder `repo_data`.

However, when I checkout that repo `B` (`testrepo`) and install it by itself, this **does** create a folder `repo_data` inside  `lib/python3.8/site-package`.

So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393849

Comment: No, the other answer does not answer my question. `git+http` does not work, `git+ssh` does not work, with and without spaces does not work. ssh asks for password, which is a no-go

Comment: How do you install repo `A`? Does `pip install 'testrepo @ git+https://mygitlab.ch/somegroup/testrepo.git'` work in command line?

Comment: With `pip install git+https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@mygitlab.ch/somegroup/testrepo.git` from within a gitlab CI.